# How can I decrypted SMIME mail smime.7ps file - java mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to read a multipart/signed mail with java mail, but when i am reading the .mime , I do not see the original attachments , the are original attachments are ignored and only i can see the smime.7ps file.
Here is the code that i use :

```
ByteArrayDataSource dataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(documentContent, "multipart/mixed");
MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart(dataSource);
for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {
                BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);
                if (bodyPart.getFileName() == null) {


                    continue; // dealing with attachments only
                        }
               System.out.println("Nombre encrypted : "+bodyPart.getFileName());
               do something
            }
```

Any different way of read the original attachments , please  let me know how i can get the body part attachments.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) library.

Comment: Thank yuo Bill,  It helped me a lot, but Can i decrypted an s/mime without private  key? The original email has a digital certificate. I can see the attachement on Outlook app. thank you.

Comment: A question better asked on the Bouncy Castle mailing list.